# How do we share multiple images or a combination of image with text at a time via Windows 8 Share Charm in c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a list of `Image Urls` & wants to `Share` those Images [from each url] at a time through `Windows 8 share charm` .
 Here is the code i used for sharing one `WriteableBitmap Image` at a time.

```
var dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataRequested;  

public void DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
        DataRequest request = args.Request;
        DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();
        try
        {   
           request.Data.SetBitmap(Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(ImageUrl)));           
        }
}
```

How we can `share a multiple images` at a time via `Share Charm` .

 Can we share a combination of image and text ?

 Please give me an idea if it is possible.

Comment: Are they local URLs or Internet URLs ?

Comment: Hi @Xyroid , urls are internet and i just need to know that is it possible sharing multiple Writeablebitmap/url Images using Share charm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

Below code shows how to share multiple image URLs via share charm.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataRequested; 
}

public void DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var Images = new List<string> 
    {
        "http://jenswinter.com/image.axd?picture=stackoverflow-logo-250.png",
        "http://en.flossmanuals.net/thunderbird/getting-support/_booki/thunderbird/static/Thunderbird-Support-tbird_support_superuser-en.jpg",
        "http://www.thomas-steinbrenner.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Stackexchange_logo.png"
    };

    var res = GetHtml(Images);
    DataRequest request = args.Request;

    // The title is required. Otherwise it won't be shared.
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Multi Image via Share Charm Using HTML.";
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();
    try
    {
        string htmlFormat = HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(res);
        request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(htmlFormat);
    }
    catch { }
    finally { deferral.Complete(); }
}

private string GetHtml(List<string> ImageUrls)
{
    string ImgTag = @"<img src='{0}' /><br />";
    string Html = @"<html>
                <head>
                <title>Multi Image via Share Charm</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                {0}
                </body>
                </html>";
    string AllImgTags = "";
    foreach (var url in ImageUrls)
    {
        AllImgTags += string.Format(ImgTag, url);
    }

    return string.Format(Html, AllImgTags);
}
```

If all are Internet URLs then you can share it by creating an HTML document from those URLs. If you have multiple `StorageFile` then you can share with [`DataPackage.SetStorageItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setstorageitems%28v=win.10%29.aspx). It accepts `IEnumerable<IStorageItem>`.

[`DataPackage.SetBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setstorageitems%28v=win.10%29.aspx) accepts only one bitmap at a time because normally the destination apps which accepts image majorly deals with single image. If app requires multiple image then I would recommend to use `DataPackage.SetStorageItems`

Comment: ' creating an HTML document from those URLs ' How it is ?